# How to find "By Name" in mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to get database values using a specific name. I want to  get all the books an author written.

This is my code to get the **first name** of the author and search for all the books he's written in *BookDB* using `Like` operator as in `mysql`

```
//get books by author name
router.route('/authorName').get((req, res) => {
    let authorName = req.params.authorName; //how can i pass this value to below regex command
    BookDB.find({"firstName": /authorName/}, (err, books) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.status(200).send(books);
    });
});
```

Problem: **How can I pass `authorName` to the {"firstName": /authorName/}**.
The way I have written, it is not set the `authorName` properly.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found `$regex`.

```
//get books by author name
router.route('/authorName').get((req, res) => {
    let authorName = req.params.authorName;
    BookDB.find({firstName: {$regex: `${authorName}`}}, (err, books) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.status(200).send(books);
    });
});
```

This will find all the results that containing this particular string `authorName` in `BookDB` database

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in the mongoose part, but you can also create regular expressions as:
new RegExp(exp: string, flags: string)

Note if you use this format,  the start and end slash has no special meaning, they would mean the string starts with a slash

Comment: I am kinda lost here :/